# Error executing AppleScript through Launchd - "Service could not initialize"

Tags: applescript, launchd, plist, macos

I've written an AppleScript that turns our CenturyLink modem's wireless radio on or off. It works when I run it manually with osascript, but now I'm trying to get it set up on a schedule with Launchd. I keep getting the following error in the Console log:

```
10/11/15 3:10:03.178 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.highintegritydesign.wirelessgenie[25674]) Service could not initialize: 14F27: xpcproxy + 13421 [1402][AD0301C4-D364-31CE-8BA7-B5DBECE64D0A]: 0xd
```

The script is called wireless-genie.scpt and it's in my home directory, with permissions 755 and owned by me. I can successfully launch it manually from my home folder with:

```
osascript wireless-genie.scpt mywirelessmodemadminuser mywirelessmodempassword
```

The plist is called com.highintegritydesign.wirelessgenie.plist, shown below. I've placed that into /Library/LaunchDaemons, and it also has permissions 755, and is owned by root.

I've run **'plutil -lint'** on com.highintegritydesign.wirelessgenie.plist and it says the plist is A-OK. I loaded the plist with **'launchctl load com.highintegritydesign.wirelessgenie.plist'**.

I'm stumped why the script won't execute. Any ideas?
Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.highintegritydesign.wirelessgenie</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>osascript</string>
        <string>/Users/north/Documents/sites/wireless-genie/wireless-genie.scpt</string>
        <string>mywirelessmodemadminuser</string>
        <string>mywirelessmodempassword</string>        
    </array>
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Minute</key>
        <integer>10</integer>
        <key>Hour</key>
        <integer>15</integer>
    </dict>
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/var/log/wirelessgenie.log</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Since you're putting the user/password in the .plist, have you tried coding it into the script to see if `launched` handles it any different?  Also just as a test I'd schedule it using `cron` to see how it handles it.  BTW you should include the version of OS X you're using in your post.  Maybe even the the AppleScript too.

Comment: I'm on OS X 10.10.5, the Script Editor says its version is 2.7, and it's generating AppleScript 2.4. Yes, I've tried coding the same username/password into the script and it works fine. I have not tried cron. If that works it would definitely point the finger at the plist. But, that won't help be diagnose what's wrong with the plist.

Comment: So if you coded the user/password into the script and `launchd` was able to start it okay, then what the issue?  Why can't you leave it that way instead of passing the user/password to the script?  It if does work with the user/password embedded in the script with `launchd` but not passed to it via `launchd` then the issue appear that you can't pass it via `launchd` and leaving it embedded is the way to go.  BTW when I said "_Maybe even the the AppleScript too_", I meant the actual AppleScript not its version number.

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I mis-understood. The script worked when I coded the user name and password into it, but ran it manually. I have yet to get it to work when executed through Launchd.

Comment: The script is up on Github at https://github.com/northk/wireless-genie.

Comment: Have you tried placing the AppleScript outside the Users Home Folder, like in `/Applications` and does `launchd` still fail to run it successfully?